# linear-gradients not working in mobile web browsers

Tags: android, css, ios, mobile

I am writing a mobile web-app and I was wondering if someone could help me understand and fix these linear-gradients so that they work in both `Safari-mobile` and the `Android-browser`.

I believe I am using every vendor-prefix properly and I even provide a fallback background-color, but whenever I view the app on a mobile device, the element whose background the gradients are applied to is transparent. In other words, the background is transparent and the gradients are not showing up on mobile devices. Meaning, even the fall-back colour is not working either.

The even more weird thing is that they (the gradients) show up on the mobile simulators for android and `iOS`.

Can someone please help me fix these gradients so they work on both desktop and mobile devices and also teach me how to do working fallback background-colors and background-images ?

I would really appreciate any and all help!

Here is what I have so far:

```
background:#fff;
background:transparent -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.65), rgba(255,255,255,.9));
background:transparent url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background:transparent -o-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,.65) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.9) 100%);
background:transparent -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,.65) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.9) 100%);
background:transparent -webkit-gradient(linear, 0%, 0%, 0%, 100%, from(rgba(255,255,255,.65), to(rgba(255,255,255,.9));
background:transparent -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,.65) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.9) 100%);
background:transparent linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,.65) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.9) 100%);
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If even your flat fallback color isn't appearing, it sounds like the browser "thinks" it's applying one of the gradients, but isn't rendering it correctly. Maybe try removing all of the gradients except one for a specific device (e.g., try just `-webkit-linear-gradient()` on Mobile Safari) and see if it renders.

Comment: @daGUY i tried just the -webkit-linear-gradient() alone and then the -webkit-gradient alone and both yielded the same results. It seems like the browser thinks it is properly displaying those two, but it is not.

Comment: remember that you add point to the marked question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work for every browser (even mobile ones) just tested it:

```
#element {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(black, transparent); /* FF 3.6+ */  
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(black, transparent); /* IE10 */  
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #000000), color-stop(100%, #ffffff)); /* Safari 4+, Chrome 2+ */  
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(black, transparent); /* Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+ */  
    background: -o-linear-gradient(black, transparent); /* Opera 11.10 */  
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr=transparent); /* IE6 & IE7 */  
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr=transparent)"; /* IE8+ */  
    background: linear-gradient(black, transparent); /* the standard */  
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Check this two good web sites for css on browsers:

- [Site 1](http://praktikanten.brueckenschlaeger.org/2011/05/18/css-gradient-and-mobile-browsers)
- [Site 2](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-linear-gradient-syntax/)

  *(I tested it on iOS 5.1.1 with this demo http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/4Kwb4/)*

Hope it helps!

Comment: All I did was replace the colours with my start-colour and my end-colour and it is not working (I am getting a transparent fill in both desktop and mobile browsers now).

I have a feeling this is due to my colours being rgba values. I think I am going to go back to  transparent-png images for the background...

Comment: Glad it helped, in the fiddle I just updated I used the transparency you needed.

Comment: Sanchez oh okay, thank you for the fiddle. That helped explain some how to make a colour to transparent gradient :-)

Comment: @user1518176 No problem, remember that you can upvote the solution if it helped you, that way we can all help each other, and welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: @FarzadA sorry for the delay, still not working? what browser are you using?

Comment: @Luis The default android browser on Android 2.3.6

Answer (score 5):

In mobile safari at least, you can't use the keyword `transparent`, you have to use `rgba(255,255,255,0)` instead. Proof: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Gradients/Gradient.html

Search for transparent, you will see even in their official document, they use `rgba` for transparent color.

Comment: this still holds true for transparent keyword in iOS 14.4 with firefox and chrome. this fix works +1

Answer (score 1):

is the property transparent necessary?

see: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: The only reason I put the transparent keyword is to overwrite the fallback background-color if one of the gradient methods were accepted.

I removed the keyword and I still get the same results. A transparency in mobile instead of a gradient.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using 'backgroundImage' instead of 'backgroundColor'